# Bash Grepping And Removing Duplicates

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

For my website I keep a record of the pages visited by a user.

It looks like this:

```
    admin viewed: page.php
    cata viewed: login.php
    noMadz viewed: buy.php
    floringg0d viewed: search.php
    noMadz viewed: trial.php
```

How could I use a grep command to make a list of the users to look like this:

```
    admin
    cata
    noMadz
    floringg0d
```

I also want to remove duplicates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

With `awk`:

```
awk '!a[$1]++{print $1}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk alone:

```
awk '!($1 in seen){seen[$1]++; print $1}' file
admin
cata
noMadz
floringg0d
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` only :

```
$ awk '!($1 in tmp){tmp[$1]=$1} END {asort(tmp); for (i in tmp){print tmp[i]}}' file
admin
cata
floringg0d
noMadz
```

No need to use other command or program like `sort`, `uniq` or `cat` with `awk`.

Using `cut` and `sort` :

```
$ cut -d " " -f1 file|sort -u
admin
cata
floringg0d
noMadz
```

No need to use `uniq` in this case.

Using `egrep` and `sort` :

```
$ egrep -o "^[A-Za-z0-9]+" file|sort -u
admin
cata
floringg0d
noMadz
```

Comment: Why we go for a tougher one, if a simple answer is available?

Comment: @AvinashRaj The solution with `awk` may be longer (not harder), but more efficient than `awk` solutions whose output is unnecessarily redirected to other programs ;)

Comment: However, the solution of @anubhava is shorter to write and produces the same result, so that's a good solution.

Comment: +1 for not to get, _awk solutions whose output is unnecessarily diverted to other program_

Answer (score 1):

you will want to use cut here

```
cat <yourfile> | cut -f1 -d" " | sort | uniq
```

and if you wanted to count the number of users you could do this

```
cat <yourfile> | cut -f1 -d" " | sort | uniq -c
```

and if you wanted to sort by the number of times users appeared

```
cat <yourfile> | cut -f1 -d" " | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

cut, sort and uniq are your friends. Just remember that you always have to sort before you uniq.

Comment: You don't need `cat` here. Should be `cut -f1 -d" " <yourfile> | sort | uniq`

Comment: That's true, I was trying to show that you can pipeline some other input into the `cut`, which is the most common usage of `cut`, `sort` etc. For example `grep something file | cut ...`

Comment: Don't need both `sort` and `uniq` either for the first one, `cut -f1 -d" " | sort -u`

Comment: I don't think there's ever a use for `grep something file | cut ...` since you can just do `awk '/something/{print ...}' file`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk,

```
awk '{ print $1 }' file | sort -u
```

Example:

```
$ (echo "admin viewed: page.php"; echo "cata viewed: login.php"; echo "noMadz viewed: buy.php"; echo "noMadz viewed: trial.php") | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort -u
admin
cata
noMadz
```

Comment: You should use `sort -u` instead of `sort|uniq` and it's not useful to use other command or program with awk (see my answer for example).